# Entity Framework doesn't generate navigation property despite having valid foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity

I've seen similar questions but I don't see the connection between them and my issue and I think my problem is much simpler than those.

I'm using EF with a code-first approach which was working fine until I started adding explicit data annotations to my models (`Required`, and `ForeignKey`)

This may be an EF identity problem, or just a EF code-first problem

My model:

```
public class GroupMembership
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }

    [Required, ForeignKey("GroupID")]
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
    [Required, ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Now the problem is when I try to add an instance:

```
GroupMembership grpMem = new GroupMembership()
{
    GroupID = grpID,
    UserID = userID,
};
context.GroupMemberships.Add(grpMem);
context.SaveChanges();
```

I get an error when trying to call `SaveChanges()`, and upon closer inspection I see that the `ApplicationUser` navigation property is null despite having a valid `UserID`. Meanwhile, the `Group` navigation property was successfully generated using `GroupID`.

`UserID` is the string ID associated with the current `ApplicationUser`, which I retrieve using

```
string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

Comment: What is the error you get by calling SaveChanges()

Comment: "Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details." When I explore 'EntityValidationErrors' for more details it only reiterates that its a validation error. I believe the validation error is because EF is attempting to add a GroupMembership object which has a null value for the 'User' reference, but this 'User' field is annotated as Required so the validation is failing.

Comment: Go the EntityValidationErrors property of the exception and show us the content :)

Comment: All it says there is that the error count is 1, and that the detail for the error is "{System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult}"

Comment: It's weird. Because all two properties are marked as virtual and if you enabled 'Lazy Loading' on your context then all navigational properties must be loaded on demand but it's not seem to be the case for User property.

Because your navigational properties have associated foreign key properties then just put `Required` data annotation on them.

Comment: highly doubt that it will work, but it's worth a try. did you try moving your required annotations to the fields instead of the navigation properties?

Comment: @LiranBo this is what I say in my last sentence :) => "Because your navigational properties have associated foreign key properties then just put Required data annotation on them."

Comment: @CodeNotFound :) you are right.. I didn't notice..

Comment: LiranBo and CodeNotFound It seems you guys found the answer! I am now able to SaveChanges(). If one of you wants to re-enter your solution as an answer to the question I will select it, otherwise I can do that myself. Curiously, before the changes are saved I still notice that the 'User' navigation property is null in the GroupMembership object. Yet it works... The 'Group' navigation property does not behave like this. Do you guys know why by chance?

Comment: I added my answer fot that solution. Glad that works but it still weird why User property is not loaded on demand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try moving your required annotations to the fields instead of the navigation properties, like this:

```
public class GroupMembership
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserID { get; set; }  
    [ForeignKey("GroupID")]
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

To be honest I have no idea why the `groupID` thing worked, unless it is saved before you even edit it.

Notice that you got the error since the you didn't set the nav property in your code, you just set the foreign key values, this is also why you need to move the annotations.

Just as an alternative, I think that you can keep the Required annotation in case you also set it in your code before the savechanges().

Comment: you should give the answer to @CodeNotFound, +1 is enough. happy to help anyway..

Answer (score 2):

> I get an error when trying to call SaveChanges(), and upon closer inspection I see that the ApplicationUser navigation property is null despite having a valid UserID. Meanwhile, the Group navigation property was successfully generated using GroupID.

It's weird. Because all two properties are marked as virtual and if you enabled 'Lazy Loading' on your context then all navigational properties must be loaded on demand but it's not seem to be the case for User property.

Because your navigational properties have associated foreign key properties :

- `GroupID` for `Group`
- `UserID` for `User`

Then just put `Required` data annotation on them like the following code :

```
public class GroupMembership
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GroupID")]
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```